# Laravel 4 Eloquent relations query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

I have a project with main table 'Qsos' and bunch of relations. Now when I try to create advanced search I don't really know how to query all relations at the same time. Qso model has following:

```
    public function band()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Band');
}

public function mode()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Mode');
}

public function prefixes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Prefix');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function customization() {
    return $this->hasOne('Customization');
}
```

Then I have SearchController with following code that has to return collection of all Qsos following required conditions:

```
$qsos = Qso::withUser($currentUser->id)
                    ->join('prefix_qso','qsos.id','=','prefix_qso.qso_id')
                    ->join('prefixes','prefixes.id','=','prefix_qso.prefix_id')
                    ->where('prefixes.territory','like',$qTerritory)
                    ->withBand($qBand)
                    ->withMode($qMode)
                    ->where('call','like','%'.$input['qCall'].'%')
                    ->orderBy('qsos.id','DESC')
                    ->paginate('20');
```

And then in view I need to call $qso->prefixes->first() and $qso->prefixes->last() (Qso and Prefix has manyToMany relation) but both return null. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the eloquent code that I found working but taking VERY long time to process:

```
            $qsos = Qso::withUser($currentUser->id)
                    ->with('prefixes')
                    ->withBand($qBand)
                    ->withMode($qMode)
                    ->where('call','like','%'.$input['qCall'].'%')
                    ->whereHas('prefixes', function($q) use ($qTerritory) {
                        $q->where('territory','like',$qTerritory);
                    })
                    ->orderBy('qsos.id','DESC')
                    ->paginate('20');
```

Comment: If I take away with('prefixes') speed becomes acceptable